# Problem 3-way merge sorting strings in C#

Tags: c#

I recently stumbled upon a problem with using 3-way merge sort algorythm, but with strings.
As you see i tried to convert it from integer version that i found on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-merge-sort/ ,but i am stuck by the part where it has recursive method called:

> mergeSort3WayRec

that looks like that:

```
void mergeSort3WayRec(int gArray[], int low, 
                  int high, int destArray[])  
{  

// If array size is 1 then do nothing  
if (high - low < 2)  
    return; 



// Splitting array into 3 parts  
int mid1 = low + ((high - low) / 3);  
int mid2 = low + 2 * ((high - low) / 3) + 1;  

// Sorting 3 arrays recursively  
mergeSort3WayRec(destArray, low, mid1, gArray);  
mergeSort3WayRec(destArray, mid1, mid2, gArray);  
mergeSort3WayRec(destArray, mid2, high, gArray);  

// Merging the sorted arrays  
merge(destArray, low, mid1, mid2, high, gArray);  
}
```

And i have no clue how to make it string-friendly. Down below is what i have done already. Any tips or help?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

    public void merge(string[] sArray, string low, string mid1, string mid2, string high, string[] destSArray)
    {
        string i = low, j = mid1, k = mid2, l = low;
        {
            while((i.Length<mid1.Length) && (j.Length < mid2.Length) && (k.Length < high.Length))
            {
                if(sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray,l)].Length < sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, k)].Length)
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int iss = Array.IndexOf(sArray, i);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[iss++];
                }
                else
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int ks = Array.IndexOf(sArray, k);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[ks++];
                }
            }

            while ((i.Length < mid1.Length) && (j.Length < mid2.Length))
            {
                if (sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, i)].Length < sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, j)].Length)
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int iss = Array.IndexOf(sArray, i);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[iss++];
                }
                else
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int js = Array.IndexOf(sArray, j);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[js++];
                }
            }

            while ((j.Length < mid2.Length) && (k.Length < high.Length))
            {
                if (sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, j)].Length < sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, k)].Length)
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int js = Array.IndexOf(sArray, j);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[js++];
                }
                else
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int ks = Array.IndexOf(sArray, k);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[ks++];
                }
            }

            while ((i.Length < mid1.Length) && (k.Length < high.Length))
            {
                if (sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, i)].Length < sArray[Array.IndexOf(sArray, k)].Length)
                {
                    int iss = Array.IndexOf(sArray, i);
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[iss++];
                }
                else
                {
                    int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                    int ks = Array.IndexOf(sArray, k);
                    destSArray[ls++] = sArray[ks++];
                }
            }

            while (i.Length < mid1.Length)
            {
                int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                int iss = Array.IndexOf(sArray, i);
                destSArray[ls++] = sArray[iss++];
            }
            while (j.Length < mid2.Length)
            {
                int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                int js = Array.IndexOf(sArray, j);
                destSArray[ls++] = sArray[js++];
            }
            while (k.Length < high.Length)
            {
                int ls = Array.IndexOf(sArray, l);
                int ks = Array.IndexOf(sArray, k);
                destSArray[ls++] = sArray[ks++];
            }
        }
    }

    public void mergeSort3Way(string[] sArray, int n)
    {

        if (n == 0)
            return;

        string[] fArray = new string[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fArray[i] = sArray[i];

        }
        mergeSort3Way(fArray, 0, n, sArray);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica im new to stackoverflow, thought that maybe if i add tag people with c++ knowledge still could help

Comment: C# and C++ are totally separate languages.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica i deleted c++ tag. Thank you.

Comment: Whats the **exact** problem with this code?

Comment: @NicoHaase i need examples or explanation how do i make integer method to work with strings

Answer (score -1):

People are downvoting your question because it looks like you are trying to offload task that was given to you to StackOverflow, this is not what this site is for. Here's what I would recommend :

1 figure out how does the code for integers work. This is essential step. It may be hard to do; so maybe you want to start with easier algorithms. Read on bubble sort, write bubble sort for integers, write bubble sort for strings, examine the difference.

2 Debug the code that you have for integers. Do you understand what every line does and what would happen if you removed it? Do you understand what every variable is for? Do you understand why particular variable has specific value at a given time during runtime?

After completing those two steps you should be able to change the code to work with strings instead of integers without an issue.